# installing R library on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r

I am trying to install an R package which is called `karyoploteR` using the following command:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("karyoploteR")
```

but when I called `library()`, I got this error:

```
> library(karyoploteR)
Error in library(karyoploteR) : there is no package called ‘karyoploteR’
```

then I tried this command:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("karyoploteR")
```

when I called the package, again I got the same error. Do you know how to install this package on `Ubuntu 18.04`?

Comment: Do you get exactly the same error when running the second commands? I'm on windows here, but the instalation went fine

Comment: @Fino: yes I got the same error.

Comment: Did you wait for installation to complete? How are you running the second command? At command line or in an IDE like RStudio? Carefully read the output of `install` command. It may have erred out.

Comment: yes it was finished. command line. it was completely done. when I called the library I got the same error.